# Is it safe to reinstall Python on El Capitan?

Tags: python, macos, reinstall

Is it safe to reinstall Python 2.7.10 on El Capitan Mac OS X?
I reinstalled my Python 2.7.10, and updated to Python 2.7.11
I reinstalled with command 'brew reinstall python'
Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"safe"`?

Comment: Did something go wrong when you did this?

Comment: @MatthewCliatt Probably exactly what the word, "safe", means. Which is "protected from or not exposed to danger or risk; not likely to be harmed or lost."

Comment: @zwol: I'd expect a lot to go wrong when someone replaces the system Python on OS X...

Comment: @MartijnPieters It isn't clear to me that that is what the OP did...

Comment: @zwol: that I agree with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't safely update the system-provided Python. Too many moving parts of the operating system and 3rd-party software relies on what the OS provides rather than what you want to use.

You can install Python via brew safely however, as it doesn't *replace* the system Python. Brew asks you to update your `PATH` variable, and *in your terminal* with an updated `PATH` you'll automatically use the brew-provided Python. This leaves the system Python in-place to be used by everything else.